# Single column gallery with flexbox with certain divs split in two

Tags: css, flexbox

I am making use of a gallery which represents a column containing either one or two `<div>` elements spanning across the entire width. The columns containing multiple `<div>` elements also contain images with different height and width properties. I would like these columns to be the same height and then fill the width as much as possible whenever there is extra space between them.

I would use a flexbox `<div>` element with a fixed width and a `flex-wrap` property. The `<div>` elements that are to span the entire width have a property `max-width: 100%`. A row with multiple items are inside a container `<div>` element which spans and then each in another box `<div>` element. I could get the two on the same lines, but since they vary in sizes I would not want each image to be 50% width, because then the empty space is above and below an item instead of between them.

I have tried tinkering with `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`, however none of these seem ever to be exact. I also considered switching the `<div>` elements with two items to `flex-direction: column` and then wrap these. This however did not work for me.

```css
.column {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.smallContain {
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.smallBox {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.largeBox {
  min-width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="smallContain">
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgS">
        </div>
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgS">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="box largeBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgL">
        </div>
      <div class="smallContain">
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgS">
        </div>
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgS">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="box largeBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgL">
        </div>
      <div class="smallContain">
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="smallContain">
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgS">
        </div>
        <div class="box smallBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgS">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="box largeBox">
          <img src="#" class="imgL">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

(Within the example above, the `.imgS` class refer to small images and `.imgL` class refer to large images)

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbVYa.jpg) of what I'm hoping to get it to look like.

Comment: Hi Jawn, welcome to SO. Could you please elaborate your problem more specifically and clearly? It is hard for anyone who reads your question to understand the problem you are facing. For any more information, please refer to [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit hard to understand, even so I gave it a try, maybe what your looking is something like this?

```css
.grid {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid .item {
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.grid .item.smallBox {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.grid .item.smallBox img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
.grid .item.largeBox {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.grid .item img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/280x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/280x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item largeBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/1920x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/480x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/250x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item largeBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/1440x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/250x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/480x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item largeBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/1440x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/500x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item smallBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/150x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item largeBox">
    <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/1440x500" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: That is the look of the desired result forma-wise. I'm thinking its just not possible to have it in a flexbox design while maintaining the photos correct proportions. I managed to do it by manually resizing the images to a set width and height, but it isn't responsive. I'll have to do it with media queries. Thank you for looking at it, and I apologize how confusing the wording was.